# Retrieving specific subjects/schema from Confluent Kafka Schema Registry

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry, confluent-cloud

I am using the Confluent Kafka Schema registry and have some schema/subjects defined.

Few examples:

```
  dev.delivery.kafka.delivery-reason-value
  dev.delivery.kafka.delivery-day-value
  dev.travel.kafka.places-ice-value
```

When I use confluent CLI and connect to the registry, I run the below commands:

```
#this gives me all the subjects/schemas defined in the registry --perfectly fine :)
confluent schema-registry subject list --prefix ":*:"
```

But, when I want to retrieve the specific topic's schema, for instance only the schema which has travel word in it

```
#this gives me "No Subjects."
confluent schema-registry subject list --prefix ":travel:"
```

OR

```
confluent schema-registry subject list --prefix ":*travel*:"
```

Can anyone help me here if I am missing something on the wild cards within the prefix?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Confluent CLI is closed source, so not really sure how it works. I would just use the REST API directly on `/subjects` and parse the response.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need that CLI. This is easily done with Python, for example.

```py
import requests

r = requests.get('http://registry:8081/subjects')
for subject in r.json():
  if 'travel' in subject:  # example
    print(subject)
```